# Alignment of TikZ Pics in TabularX

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tabularx

What is the easiest way to get that last square aligned the same was as the first two? Do I need to create a `\newcolumntype` that somehow centers the content both vertically and horizontally? If so, how do I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{16cm}{C{5cm}C{5cm}Y}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

&

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

&

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}\\

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not weird. That's what I'd expect. Presumably, you expected something else. Since you don't say what, it is hard to be more helpful.

Comment: @cfr I agree. I just fixed the title. I just don't know how to fix the situation.

Comment: Thanks. That's much clearer. The documentation offers `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` to change what `X` does but I'm not sure you can do it for just one column.

Comment: The solution proposed for @cfr works for me if you suppress \\ on last `tabularx` row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation suggests changing the format of `X` columns with

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

which seems to work here, although the result is too wide for the text block, so I added `geometry` and made a bit more room.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,geometry}
\geometry{scale=.8}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% from the documentation
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{16cm}{C{5cm}C{5cm}Y}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned squares]